# IOS how to get Facebook extended permission dialog

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm creating an iPhone app that will publish photos to the Facebook pages on behalf of the user(where the user is the administrator). In order to do that I need to pop up the dialog (that user can give permission to my app) to manage_pages. How can I do that? Im using the latest Facebook SDK, Any help.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession#requestNewPublishPermissions%3AdefaultAudience%3AcompletionHandler%3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *permissions = 
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"manage_pages", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                        /* handle success + failure in block */
                                    }];
```

Comment: Now you have to use this:- (void)requestNewReadPermissions:(NSArray *)readPermissions
                completionHandler:(FBSessionRequestPermissionResultHandler)handler;

Comment: If using Facebook SDK V4.x, here's the only solution that worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487389/how-to-rerequest-email-permission-using-facebook-ios-sdk-4-x