# How to “rerequest” email permission using Facebook iOS SDK 4.x?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am integrating FacebookSDK 4.x integration with custom UI and using following method to log-in and also getting email permission from user.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);            
        }
        else if (result.isCancelled){
            NSLog(@"Cancled");
        }
        else
        {
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
            { 
                NSLog(@"Granted all permission");
                if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
                {
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                    {
                        if (!error)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"%@",result);
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Not granted");
            }
        }
    }];
```

This works great unless the user denies access to "email". I see in the FacebookSDK docs that I can re-request access to the user's email one time. According to the FB docs: as given in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication)

```
If someone has declined a permission for your app, the login dialog won't let your app re-request the permission unless you pass auth_type=rerequest along with your request.
```

**Enabling Re-authentication**

> During your chosen login flow we showed you how to use the Login
>   Dialog and OAuth to authenticate someone and request permissions from
>   them. To re-authenticate, you can use these same steps with additional
>   parameters to force it:
>
> auth_type: this parameter specifies the requested authentication
>   features (as a comma-separated list). Valid options are:
>           https - checks for the presence of a secure Facebook session and asks for re-authentication if it is not present
>           reauthenticate - asks the person to re-authenticate unconditionally
>
> ```
> auth_nonce: includes an app generated alphanumeric nonce which can be used to provide replay protection. See how to check an auth_nonce
> ```
>
> for more.
>
> Here is an example using the JavaScript SDK that triggers
>   re-authentication using an auth_type of reauthenticate:
>
> **FB.login(function(response) {
>       // Original FB.login code   }, { auth_type: 'reauthenticate' })**
>
> Note that the body of the response contains the auth_type parameter
>   you specified, for example:
>
> access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&expires=SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES&auth_type=reauthenticate

How do I pass "auth_type=rerequest" to Facebook's servers via the iOS SDK? Is there a special method for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved issue by recalling the method :

**[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)**

I need to pass **auth_type: 'rerequest'** while requesting again and i get it in the documentation of this method i get the description :

> Use this method when asking for read permissions. You should only ask
>   for permissions when they   are needed and explain the value to the
>   user. You can inspect the result.declinedPermissions to also   provide
>   more information to the user if they decline permissions.
>
> If `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is not nil, it will be
>   treated as a reauthorization for that user   and will pass the
>   "rerequest" flag to the login dialog.

just the problem was i was calling **logout** Method of FbSDKLoginManager class. This will clear the token and it  will takes it as the old permission not re-requested permission.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but how did you pass auth_type: 'rerequest'?

Comment: Actually i am not passing 're-request' to facebook explicitly but when ever you are logged in and call [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) method again it will take as 're-request'. so just recall this method after some time that's it yes but you must not call logout method before calling this method AGAIN. hope it will help you :)

Comment: so how to do get the users email when you want to use it ?

Comment: @iPR +1 for not calling logout();

Comment: I am not able to relogin. Please help me

Comment: @EktaPadaliya what exactly issue you are facing ?

Comment: You said after some time, can you please tell me how much time it expects? For my case when I call logInWithReadPermissions this after declining some permissions with after proper alert why I need permissions then it takes me to the login screen instead of permission dialog  so can tell why this is happing in my case?

Comment: @python you can call the next method after 0.01 sec delay as i am doing.

Comment: This does not work for me. Using FBSDKLoginKit(4.35.0)

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need to pass or call auth_type:rerequest. This is already done by facebook. If you check FBSDKLoginManager, the code does it for you.

```
-(NSDictionary *)logInParametersWithPermissions:(NSSet *)permissions
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) 
       {
             loginParams[@"auth_type"] = @"rerequest";
       }
}
```