# ParseFacebookUtils Android auth_type: 'reauthenticate'

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.19.1, Parse 1.8.0,
During login via Facebook, my app asks for basic permissions only - public profile & email.
When using ParseFacebookUtils.logIn method, how to re-ask declined permissions?

I didn't find any param where I could specify auth_type.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to explicitly call `auth_type: 'reauthenticate'`. You should only recall `logInWithReadPermissions` and this will make the job.

So make sure you are calling:

```
 Collection<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends");   
 loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissions);
```

This will only work if you are not calling `logout` before the new `logInWithReadPermissions`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487389/how-to-rerequest-email-permission-using-facebook-ios-sdk-4-x) may help you with more details.