# How to re-prompt the permission from the user with FacebookSDK?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I want to implement functionality using FacebookSDK.

As a sample application you can check the url:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/handling-declined-permissions#reprompt

I have written this code but it is not working for me as expected.

```
//Callback function for default FBLogin Button
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    print("User Logged In")

    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Process error
        print("Processing Error : \(error)")
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if result.isCancelled
    {
        // Handle cancellations
        print("user is cancelled the login FB")
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("result : \(result)")

        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.declinedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            print("email is declined")
            // Do work
            loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            loginManager!.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ [unowned self](result, error) -> Void in

                    if error == nil
                    {
                        self.fetchUserData()
                    }

                })
        }
        else
        {
            var readPermissions : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            Constants.isUserLoggedIn = true
            fetchUserData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a few issues with the provided snippet, which I'll walk through.  Revised code at the bottom.

**Compile Error**

When I try to run your code as given, I get a compile error

```
loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager!.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ [unowned self](result, error) -> Void in
```

> use of unresolved identifier 'loginManager'

From the looks of it, you have saved an optional FBSDKLoginManager on your view controller, but that isn't necessary, and will mess up your attempt to reprompt the user for email.

Instead of getting a second chance to give you access to email, they will just see the "You have already authorized [app name here]" dialog.

(The "rerequest" is finicky and implicit unfortunately... I learned all I know, which isn't much, from this post- [How to “rerequest” email permission using Facebook iOS SDK 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487389/how-to-rerequest-email-permission-using-facebook-ios-sdk-4-x))

**Timing**

The other major issue seems just to be about the timing of your call to re-request the permissions.  When I ran your code, and unchecked email access, I was shown a blank Facebook Popup.

However, when, as in the example app, I wrapped the re-prompt in a dialog with explaining what I need the email for, I saw the re-prompt I was expecting.

**Other**

- Added Error Handling to your reprompt attempt (otherwise you hit force unwrap of nil errors)
- Removed unnecessary calls to

  > self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

**Revised Code**

```
//Callback function for default FBLogin Button
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    print("User Logged In")

    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Process error
        print("Processing Error : \(error)")
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
    }
    else if result.isCancelled
    {
        // Handle cancellations
        print("user is cancelled the login FB")
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
    }
    else //permissions were granted, but still need to check which ones
    {
        if result.declinedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "We need your email address to proceed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { action in
                // Handle cancellations
                print("user is cancelled the login FB")
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

            })
            let reRequestAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Grant Access", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
                let fbsdklm = FBSDKLoginManager()
                fbsdklm.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        // Process error
                        print("Processing Error : \(error)")
                        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                    }
                    else if result.isCancelled {
                        // Handle cancellations
                        print("user is cancelled the login FB")
                        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Got Email Permissions!")
                        //proceed
                    }
                }
            })

            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            alert.addAction(reRequestAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else
        {
            print("Got Email Permissions!")
            //proceed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing exactly same but in my case when I call logInWithReadPermissions after declining some permissions. I call this method after proper alert which tells why I need permissions then it takes me to the login screen instead of permission dialog directly, so can you tell why this is happing in my case?